# How to create a click counter?

Tags: javascript

I need a click counter that counts clicks per second for 16 minutes using js or php preferably

JavaScript:

```
var clicks = document.querySelectorAll('.click-trigger'); // IE8
for (var i = 0; i < clicks.length; i++) {
    clicks[i].onkeypress = function () {
        var now = new Date
        now.getSeconds()
        var idTime = this.getAttribute('data-click-id')
        var id = this.getAttribute('data-click-id');
        var time = 'id=' + idTime;
        var post = 'id=' + id; // post string
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('POST', 'contador.php', true);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (req.readyState != 4 || req.status != 200) return;
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = req.responseText;
        };
        req.send(post);
        req.send(postTime)
    }
}
```

PHP:

```
$file = 'contador.txt'; // caminho para o arquivo de texto que armazena 
contagens $fh = fopen($file, 'r+');
$id = $_REQUEST['id']; // publicado a partir da página
$idTime = $_REQUEST['id'];
$lines = '';
while(!feof($fh)){
  $line = explode('||', fgets($fh)); $item = trim($line[0]);
  $num = trim($line[1]);
    if(!empty($item)){
      if($item == $id){
        $num++; // contagem de incremento em 1 echo $num;
      }
      $lines .= "$item||$num\r\n";
  }
}
file_put_contents($file, $lines);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

```
$clickcount = explode("\n", file_get_contents('contador.txt'));
foreach($clickcount as $line){
  $tmp = explode('||', $line);
  $count[trim($tmp[0])] = trim($tmp[1]);
}
```

Comment: there isn't any php in this question

Comment: `onkeypress` is emitted after a key is pressed not a click.
First of all, you should use `onclick` instead

Comment: yes i use click for key this is my intention i only need I need a click counter that counts clicks per second for 16 minutes using js or php preferably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a weird question as I like them (!) I may have completely misunderstood it.

But anyway, I can tell that initiating an XMLHttpRequest on every single click looks hazardous. Those requests certainly will take more time than the user click speed.

I suggest to run a `setTimeout()` and store the results when the delay is expired. That delay is 5 seconds in the snippet below.

```js
var clicks = document.querySelectorAll('.click-trigger')

var data = {}

clicks.forEach(function(el){
  el.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    let id = el.getAttribute('data-click-id')
    
    if(data[id]==undefined){  // on frist click, define the data object property for that button id
      data[id] = 0
    }
    data[id]++  // increment the count
    
    // Show click count
    el.querySelector(".count").innerText = "- Clicked " + data[id] + " times"
  })
})

var delay = setTimeout(function(){
  console.log("Delay expired.... Saving.")
  
  // You now can implement an XMLHttpRequest here and send the data.
  console.log(data)
},5000) // Just five seconds here.... But set to 960000 for 16 minutes.
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="click-trigger" data-click-id="btn_1">Click me! <span class="count"></span></button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="click-trigger" data-click-id="btn_2">Click me! <span class="count"></span></button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="click-trigger" data-click-id="btn_3">Click me! <span class="count"></span></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank's can you help me on how to count these clicks per second?